# Synchronization in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have a use case like this:

When user clicks on a radio button I make an ajax call to get some information dependant on the user selection. When user clicks on a link I use the information form AJAX call to display an alert.

I need:

1. to ensure the result of the ajax calls are written in the correct
   order
2. If the user to open the alert, before then the AJAX call is finished I want to display him a waiting icon, otherwise display him
   the alert
3. If the response from AJAX doesn't comein 2s I will display the alert anyway

I am not really asking how to do this specific use case in JS, since I can figure out how to combine timer, jQuery ajax callbacks and so on.

I see the problem in a more generic way:

we have three events (AJAX success, user click, timeout) and I wanto to associate some code to be triggered by some conditions on the events. Is there any framework that allows to associate actions to a combination of events?

Or am I just using the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - If the response order is important, it's not useful to allow multiple parallel requests, which means when the user will select a radio button, you should queue the operations. That's very easy to achieve with promises.

E.g.

```
var promiseQueue;

function processRequest(radioValue) {
    return $.ajax({ ... }).done(/*handle request*/);
}

function onRadioClicked() {
    var radioValue = this.value; //assuming this is your radio element

    //if the queue was initialized, queue our next operation using "then",
    //otherwise process the request directly and initialize the queue with the
    //returned promise.
    promiseQueue = promiseQueue? 
        promiseQueue.then(processRequest.bind(null, radioValue)) :
        processRequest(radioValue);
}
```

2 - Do not use `alert` as it will block your UI. You can use jQuery UI's [Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) plugin or anything similar. Everytime a response is processed, you can check [`promiseQueue.state()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.state/) to see if there are other requests to be processed or they all have been processed.

3 - You can pass a `timeout` configuration to `$.ajax` to allow a maximum time for the request to complete. Have a look at https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/